# Hibernate criteria mapped to only one class in hierarchy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, hibernate-criteria

I have a hierarchy of entity classes mapped to my DB with Hibernate
(and don't have much room for changing the hierarchy).

This is the parent table

```
Table TMP_ROOT
| ID | NAME  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | A FOO |
| 2  | A BAR |
```

And this are the children

```
Table TMP_CHILD_FOO
| ID | COMMON | FOO |
|----|--------|-----|
| 1  | 123    | 456 |

Table TMP_CHILD_BAR
| ID | COMMON | BAR |
|----|--------|-----|
| 2  | 777    | 888 |
```

These two children tables share a field `COMMON` that I can't put in the root table because
there are other children tables that do not have it.

My tables are mapped as follows, using an abstract class for the common attribute.
(I omit getters, setters, `equals`, etc.):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TMP_ROOT")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Root {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Middle extends Root {

    @Column(name = "COMMON")
    private Long common;

}

@Entity(name = "TMP_CHILD_FOO")
public class FooChild extends Middle {

    @Column(name = "FOO")
    private Integer foo;

}

@Entity(name = "TMP_CHILD_BAR")
public class BarChild extends Middle {

    @Column(name = "BAR")
    private Integer bar;

}
```

The mapping works *mainly* as expected:

- if I query on `Root` adding filters on its fields (`ID`, `NAME`), it works
- if I query on `Root` adding filters on fields of `FooChild`/`BarChild` (`FOO` / `BAR` resp.), it works

**BUT** if i try to query on `COMMON` field, the generated SQL query only filter on one of the two tables
and completely ignores the other.

This happens, for instance, with this test (by the way, I know that `session.createCriteria(clazz)` is
 deprecated, but it's a part of code I can't easily change):

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class HibernateHierarchyTest {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        System.out.println("--DEPLOY--");
        WebArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "Test.war")
                .addClasses(Root.class,Middle.class,FooChild.class,BarChild.class, EntityManager.class)
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        return archive;
    }

    @Before
    public void preparePersistenceTest() throws Exception {
        insertData();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    private void insertData() throws Exception {
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        insertFooBar();

        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.clear();
    }

    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    private void insertFooBar() {
        FooChild foo = new FooChild();
        foo.setId(1L);
        foo.setName("THE FOO");
        foo.setCommon(456L);
        foo.setFoo(42);
        em.merge(foo);

        BarChild bar = new BarChild();
        bar.setId(2L);
        bar.setName("THE BAR");
        bar.setCommon(789L);
        bar.setBar(666);
        em.merge(bar);
    }

    @Test
    public void findRootAndChildren() {
        Class<Root> clazz = Root.class;
        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        findCommonEqualTo(clazz, session, 456L);
        findCommonEqualTo(clazz, session, 789L);
    }

    private void findCommonEqualTo(Class<Root> clazz, Session session, long value) {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(clazz);
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("common", value));
        List results = criteria.list();
        printAll(results);
    }

    private static void printAll(List results) {
        System.err.println(results.size());
        results.forEach(System.err::println);
    }
}
```

The two queries are

- `findCommonEqualTo(clazz, session, 456L);`: should find all entities with `COMMON=456`
- `findCommonEqualTo(clazz, session, 789L);`: should find all entities with `COMMON=789`

The resulting SQL, though, only filters on ONE of the tables and completely ignores the same field on the other.

```
SELECT
  root.ID       AS ID1_56_0_,
  root.NAME     AS NAME2_56_0_,
  bar.COMMON    AS COMMON1_54_0_,
  bar.BAR       AS BAR2_54_0_,
  foo.COMMON    AS COMMON1_55_0_,
  foo.FOO       AS FOO2_55_0_,
  CASE WHEN bar.ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1
  WHEN foo.ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN 2
  WHEN root.ID IS NOT NULL
    THEN 0 END   AS clazz_0_
FROM TMP_ROOT root
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_CHILD_BAR bar ON root.ID = bar.ID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN TMP_CHILD_FOO foo ON root.ID = foo.ID
WHERE bar.COMMON = ?;
```

As you can see, the generated query only uses `bar.COMMON` and there's no condition on `foo.COMMON`.

If I were to write the SQL manually, I would just use `WHERE (bar.COMMON = ? OR foo.COMMON = ?)`,
but I have no idea how to accomplish that with Hibernate criteria query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you can not easily query (like in your `SQL`) for `common` from `Root` because it does not exist in `Root` (*but I have to admit that I do not actually know how `hibernate-criteria` handles this so might still be possible some way, not so familiar with it*).

Below is my explanation & suggestion.

`common` exists only in the `Middle`. Even though after the query the result set is populated with the actual type.

> These two children tables share a field `COMMON` that I can't put in the root table because there are other children tables that do not have it.

Also I think you do not want to search `Root` if you want to find entities having `common`? More suitable option would be to query `Middle` when it comes to find entities with and by `common`.

And to achieve this - having the database as it is now and wihtout changing the hierarchy - you should change `Middle` a bit

```
@Entity // so not @MappedSuperClass
// TABLE_PER_CLASS prevents creating Middle
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Middle extends Root { .. }
```

**Update**

However if it is possible to use `JPA2.1` this could also be achieved with using `treat(..)`, for example like

```
cq.where( cb.equals( cb.treat( root, Middle.class).get("common") ) );
```

so explicitly telling how to treat or cast the `Root` when searching for some field that is actually in some of its subclass.

Comment: Unfortunately, this entities are part of a larger hierarchy, and my criteria can apply to fields in any part of the hierarchy,so I have to always query on Root (e.g. I may ask for BAR=888). If the field is in a root or leaf of the hierarchy tree, all is fine. I may try with a different inheritance strategy and see what I can do.

Comment: Ok. You can still test if changing `Middle` to `Entity` helps. Can you use CriteriaQuery defined by yourself or do you have to stick on some other pre-defined stuff?

Comment: There's a couple of layers of something I'd call a home-made "query generator"... but with some pain, I can add a custom query in it

Comment: @Damiano added a small update. Though guess that it is not so easy to create generic query constructor for these kind of situations even happened to use `JPA 2.1` or newer implementation.

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it didn't solve the problem: `TABLE_PER_CLASS` doesn't help with the query generation, the field is still applied to only one leaf table of the hierarchy. As for JPA 2.1, unfortunately the project is stuck with 2.0.. I'm gonna try anyway

Comment: @Damiano Yes, unfortunately. I use `OpenJPA`, it has this `treat(..)` even it is yet `JPA 2.0` officially. However using that  throws `abstract method exception` and not yet had time to found out if it is still possible.